# TPL Dataflow Blocks Running On UI Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, dataflow, tpl-dataflow

I am building a dataflow pipeline to do various processing (mostly I/O, but some CPU processing) that is in a naturally occurring flow.  The flow is currently in this basic pattern:

1. Load Data from File
2. Parse Record using Transform Block
3. Serialize & Upload object to server via REST

This processing pipeline can be started automatically, or via a GUI.  For when it's started from the GUI I would like to provide progress messages to the end-user.  If I add a `BufferBlock` between step 1 & 2 and an `ActionBlock` after step 3 and set the options for them to run on the same thread as the UI, will the other blocks still run off the UI using their own threadpool?

I was looking at this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228605(v=vs.110).aspx but it wasn't very clear regarding this behavior.  Can I fire an event from the pipeline that can run on the UI thread as well to accomplish this?

EDIT:  The pipeline would be started from a `BackgroundWorker` object on the UI, and not the UI thread directly.

Comment: Are you using `DataflowBlockOptions.TaskScheduler` to make it run an the UI thread? A piece of code would help.

Comment: @Noseratio This is more of a theoretical question.  I'm still planning this feature out.  As of right now it's not reporting progress.  Using the `DataflowBlockOptions.TaskScheduler` was how I was going to tell those particular blocks to run on the UI thread.

Comment: I'd use the `Progress<T>` pattern for that and did not resort to the UI thread TaskScheduler.

Comment: @Noseratio I actually, should have been a bit more specific, it's not directly the UI thread I was thinking of using, but instead the pipeline would be started via a BackgroundWorker so it would capture the BackgroundWorker's thread's SynchronizationContext. Do you think that using `Progress<T>` to report from the pipeline to the BackgroundWorker would be a better option, and then have the BackgroundWorker fire a progresschanged event to the UI?

Comment: I think you don't need `BackgroundWorker` here. Just create `Progress<T>` on the UI thread (it does capture the s. context and uses `sc.Post` internally). Then call it from your Dataflow pipeline wherever the progress has been made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Noseratio's suggestions I actually redesigned how this done and was able to have it work without an issue.  I eliminated the `BackgroundWorker` object since it wasn't really necessary.  Instead I wrapped the entire dataflow in an asynchronous method, which takes various `Progress<T>` parameters as callbacks for progress updates.  There were no extra TPL Blocks used in order to post progress since the `Progress<T>`'s `Report()` method is called within preexisting blocks.  Additionally, since this is an async function the Task that represents the dataflow is not running on the UI thread, but instead on a threadpool thread.  The main thing to take from this is that the `Progress<T>` objects's callbacks are run on the thread they are created on since during construction they capture the current synchronization context.  Here is an example of what resolved my issue:

```
public static async Task ProcessData(IProgress<int> ReadProg, IProgress<int> UploadProg)
{
      var loadBuffer = new BufferBlock<string>();
      var parseBlock = new TransformBlock<string, MyObject>(async s =>
      {
          if(await DoSomething(s))
              ReadProg.Report(1);
          else
              ReadProg.Report(-1);
       });
       ...
       //setup of other blocks
       //link blocks
       //feed data into pipeline by adding data into the head block: loadBuffer
       //await ALL continuation tasks of the blocks
}
```

Then within the UI I created the `Progress<int>` objects and passed them into the async `ProcessData` method.  Whenever the `Process<T>.Report()` method were called in the async processing method the UI updated without issue.